# Alphabetised WordPress Posts

Tags: wordpress

How can I alphabetise (by title) my WordPress posts?

Answer (score 2):

use query_posts() before the_loop() with a parameter orderby=title
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Orderby_Parameters